# Create the database only once instead of three times

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance

Suppose I have

```
class DataBuilder:
   def __init__(self):
      self.build()
   
   def build(self):
      #Place where the logic build the database
```

and three classes which will inherit of that class

```
class StrategyOne(DataBuilder):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()

class StrategyTwo(DataBuilder):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()

class StrategyThree(DataBuilder):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
```

As the name explains, the class `DataBuilder` builds a big dataset. Suppose I call

```
strategy_one = StrategyOne()
strategy_two = StrategyTwo()
strategy_three = StrategyThree()
```

Will it build the database three times? If so, how can I avoid such thing? I just want to build the database once and then creates the three above object.

Comment: It depends on how you write the code. The database could be stored as class variable, set to `None` by default. The database is then only built if the variable is `None` yet.

Comment: Let me modify the code so it makes it obvious

Comment: Favor Composition over Inheritance. If you want the database only once, create it only once and pass it to other objects. Separation of Concerns: separate the database from other stuff. Single Responsibility: Let your classes only do one thing.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Could you show me how you would handle this?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I am very new in Python. Could you make a full answer with an example so I could understand well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a boolean variable and set it to false, then once database is built, you could switch it to true. A database will be built only if value of that that variable is false. For example:

```py
class DataBuilder:
  database_exists = False
  def __init__(self):
    self.build()

  def build(self):
    if database_exists:
      # do nothing
    else: 
      # your database code
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store the database as class variable to have at most one database:

```
class DataBuilder:
   database = None

   def __init__(self):
      self.build()
   
   def build(self):
      if DataBuilder.database is None:
         # Build database and store it in the variable "DataBuilder.database"
      # else: Do nothing
```

Comment: Could you add some more details? In my head, database=None will always be None. Am I wrong?

Comment: @David The variable can be accessed as `DataBuilder.database` (and a new value can be assigned to it). I had to correct my code, I wrote it wrongly in the first version.

Comment: Can you put more details how you would use it with the other classes and instances? If you can make it, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @David I don't know how you wanted to use these classes and why you derived them from `DataBuilder`.